# How to reload plugins/AppDomain for LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

I've observed that if I refresh or reload the dll's in LINQPad's specified Plugins directory, that I must also close and re-open the  current script for the library changes to take affect - which makes sense of course. My question is if there is a command or key that specifically does this reload without closing the script window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `Ctrl + Shift + F5`.  That unloads the application domain.  Then run the query again.

If you run into this a lot, you may want to look at the option Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Execution -> Always use Fresh Application Domains.

Comment: That seems to do it, thanks. I don't use the "Always Use Fresh Application Domains" option because several scripts or unit tests I run involve cached data, and such caches are also garbage collected when that option is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm doing a lot of message queue testing at the moment and those pesky open connections were giving me a real headache with pub/sub!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the *"Always Use Fresh Application Domains"* option you can always unload the `AppDomain` yourself.

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        // Magic goes here
    }
    finally
    {
        AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }
}
```

You'll get a warning message after successfully executing this code (*Query ended unexpectedly*), but it's still beter than changing that global configuration setting.